# AngularJS Master Detail example [ASP.NET application with WEBAPI,AngularJS]

Tags: templates, angularjs, partial

The requirements is like master detail grid, on load the master gets displayed as a table, on every detail row edit button click , need to open the detail edit form in a Modal window. There could be different templates based on detail/productTypes . For example productType1 will display few set of fields(template 1) , so on.

Have WEBAPI with REST support and understand how to build the initial Master table But not sure on how the details part.
Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML/CSS Framework provide mechanism for a dialog? If so you would have to create a directive to wrap it around the script to open the dialog.

On the master grid row ng-click will set a flag on the controller. When this flag is set to true, the code in directive will open the dialog. Within that dialog div you can use ng-include that will be bound to the url of the template (controller variable will store that url).

The template is bound to a child object in the controller scope and has the fields for the details. Setting the flag to false will close the dialog and you will have changes your main controller.